# PromQL query to find top 5 based on revenue

Tags: prometheus, promql

Considering that profile generates some revenue over a period of time and being pushed to Prometheus as a Counter, I need to find the top 5 performing profiles based on revenue. I tried with

```
topk(5,sum({__name__="ow_wt_revenue",pub_id="159409",profile_id=~""}) by (profile_id))&start=1676016000&end=1676098800&step=1h
```

However, it is not returning consistent results. Is there any way to get topk record based on given time range in Prometheus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sending the following query to [/api/v1/query](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#instant-query):

```
topk(5, sum(increase(ow_wt_revenue{pub_id="159409"}[1h]) by (profile_id)))
```

This query should return top5 profiles with the biggest revenue during the last hour (see `1h` in square brackets) ending at the timestamp specified via `time` query arg passed to `/api/v1/query`. It is assumed that the `ow_wt_revenue` is a [counter](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#counter).